# Return variable to file or direct from input

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

Use

```
with open("file.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(input())
```

or

```
x = input()
with open("file.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(x)
```

Which is better? Waiting for user and them open file or open file and wait for input?

Comment: Which ever provides the easiest code to read and maintain... these type of questions aren't really appropriate to SO.

Comment: @AChampion, OP: there is an important difference: in the first case, the user never gets asked for input if the file can't be appended to. In the latter case, the user will always be asked for input. Therefore, there is a clear distinction between the two examples in the user interface.

Answer (score 3):

Which version is better depends on the user interface you want to use: in the first case, the user never gets asked for input in the case the file can't be appended to. In the second case, there is always an input prompt before a potential writing failure.

So you should ask yourself whether the context of your examples prefers the first or the second case.

Also, in the first code sample, you can't do anything else with the user input:

```
with open("file.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(input())
# we can't use the return value of input() for further processing, 
# as it's never assigned to a variable.
```

(Of course, if you don't use the return value of `input()` elsewhere, the two code samples are the same in practice.)